# Cloth interacting with other cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

Hey guys I'm trying to make a tree simulation using cloth physics.
I want to know is it possible to connect one cloth to another cloth and have them influence each others movements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. It can be done in a variety of ways, such as using a pinning vertex group to a bone, and then have the bone constrained to another cloth piece.

However, Blender's cloth sim is not the most robust, so I'll warn you that while it is possible, it probably will not produce very good quality results. You may want to look into other rigging options.